Is it possible to write seedir output to file
I have found that seedir gives me the exact output I require, but I would like to be able to write the output to a file, is this possible?
It prints perfectly to console but I see no way of capturing this output.

"By default, the output is printed. To return a string instead, use the printout argument:"

Many thanks John, being new to asking questions here not sure how or if I can accept this as the answer


prints perfectly to console but I see no way of capturing this output

If you encounter such situation contextlib.redirect_stdout is handy, example in docs
with open('help.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        help(pow)

could be easily adapted to your case, assuming you are interested in current working directory (.) you might do
import contextlib
import seedir
with open('seedir.txt', 'w') as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        seedir.seedir('.')

